# Changing the height of a div, through animation, after .load has successfully worked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div called `#loadHere` where pages are dynamically loaded into using the `.load()` functionality. As usual, what happens is the div `#loadHere` resizes according to what ever it loads in, however, the resizing of the div is jarring because of the instantaneous load in. Is there a way to have the parent div `#loadHere` resize through `.animate()` so the sizing doesn't just jump?

Here is the function I wrote:

```
function hideMenu(fileName){
    $("#loadHere").animate({"opacity":"0"}, function(){
        $("#global-nav").animate({"height":0, "padding":0}, "slow");
        $("#backBtn").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#loadHere").load("stories/"+fileName, function(){
            $("#loadHere").animate("opacity","1");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JQuery animate(), try using CSS3 transitions. Initially hide your div with a class `hide`

```
<div id="loadHere" class="hide"></div>

// somewhere in your css file
.hide{
  opacity : 0;
}

.show{
  opacity : 1;
  transition : opacity 2s ease;
}
```

In your load callback, change the class name of the div to `show`

```
  $("#loadHere").load("stories/"+fileName, function(){
        $("#loadHere").prop('class','show');
  });
```

That's it, CSS3 will show its magic :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by loading your content into an inner div, and then resizing the container to the width and height of the inner div.

```
function hideMenu(fileName){
    $("#loadHere").animate({"opacity":"0", "width":"0", "height":"0"}, function(){
        $("#loadInner").load(fileName, function(){
            $("#loadHere").animate({
                "opacity":"1", 
                "width":$("#loadInner").width(),
                "height":$("#loadInner").height()
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/zzxhmegj/1/